# CKEDITOR - Apply bold to numbered list including numbers

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I am facing an issue with the numbered list in `ckeditor`. When I try to bold some text in `li`, only the text is getting bold, without the preceding number. This is how it looks like,

1. One
2. **Two**
3. Three

It should be like this

**2. Two**

When I check the source, I found the code like below

```
<li><strong>Two</strong></li>
```

I would like to know is there any way to change the working of `bold` button, so that it will add something like below

```
<li style="font-weight:bold">Two</li>
<p> Hello <strong>World</strong></p>
```

Comment: Just been reading about your problem here: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8741 Seems that CKEditor will not be "fixing" or implementing a solution for this. So, it looks as though to achieve what you want you will have to create yourself a plugin. However, depending on the various situations/scenarios a user is in, it may not be possible to achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: this is achievable with CSS, can I see a broader example please

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve your problem.

My solution isn't the best, because I guess that create a bold plugin, that takes care about list items would be the best solution.

I make it without using jQuery; however, using it the code should became simpler and more readable.

1. First of all, we need to define something useful for the main task:

   - **String trim**. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript).

     ```
     if (!String.prototype.trim) {
        String.prototype.trim = function() {
             return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
        };
     }
     ```
   - **String contains**. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript)

     ```
     String.prototype.contains = function(it) {
             return this.indexOf(it) != -1;
     };
     ```
   - **First child element**. The following function obtains the first child element, or not-empty text node, of the element passed as argument

     ```
     function getFirstChildNotEmpty(el) {
         var firstChild = el.firstChild;    
         while(firstChild) {
             if(firstChild.nodeType == 3 && firstChild.nodeValue && firstChild.nodeValue.trim() != '') {
                 return firstChild;
             } else if (firstChild.nodeType == 1) {
                 return firstChild;
             }
             firstChild = firstChild.nextSibling;
         }
         return firstChild;
     }
     ```
2. Now, we can define the main two functions we need:

   ```
   function removeBoldIfPresent(el) {
       el = el.$;
       var elStyle = el.getAttribute("style");
       elStyle = (elStyle) ? elStyle : '';
       if(elStyle.trim() != '' && elStyle.contains("font-weight:bold")) {
           el.setAttribute("style", elStyle.replace("font-weight:bold", ''));
       }
   }

   CKEDITOR.instances.yourinstance.on("change", function(ev) {
       var liEls = ev.editor.document.find("ol li");

       for(var i=0; i<liEls.count(); ++i) {
           var el = liEls.getItem(i);

           var nativeEl = el.$.cloneNode(true);
           nativeEl.normalize();
           var firstChild = getFirstChildNotEmpty(nativeEl);

           if(firstChild.nodeType != 1) {
               removeBoldIfPresent(el);
               continue;
           }

           var firstChildTagName = firstChild.tagName.toLowerCase()
           if(firstChildTagName == 'b' || firstChildTagName == 'strong') {
               //TODO: you also need to consider the case in which the bold is done using the style property
               //My suggest is to use jQuery; you can follow this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877903/check-if-text-in-cell-is-bold
               var textOfFirstChild = (new CKEDITOR.dom.element(firstChild)).getText().trim();
               var textOfLi = el.getText().trim();

               if(textOfFirstChild == textOfLi) {
                   //Need to make bold
                   var elStyle = el.getAttribute("style");
                   elStyle = (elStyle) ? elStyle : '';
                   if(elStyle.trim() == '' || !elStyle.contains("font-weight:bold")) {
                       el.setAttribute("style", elStyle + ";font-weight:bold;");
                   }
               } else {
                   removeBoldIfPresent(el);
               }
           } else {
               removeBoldIfPresent(el);
           }

       }
   });
   ```

You need to use the last release of CkEditor (version 4.3), and the [onchange plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/onchange) (that is included by default in the [full package](http://ckeditor.com/download)).

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor 4.1 remove your classes, styles, and attributes that is not specified in its rules.

If that's the problem, you might want to disable it by adding this line:

```
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
```

**Here is full code to use it:**

```
window.onload = function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'txt_description' );
    CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;   //please add this line after your CKEditor initialized
};
```

Please check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16779093/631652)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not sure whether you understood, what I asked. I want to configure the bold button, so that It will edit the content like the example in my question

Answer (score -1):

```
<ul class="test">
<li><span>hello</span></li>
</ul>


.test li
 {
 font-weight:bold;
 }
.test li span
 {
 font-weight:normal;
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't necesarily have anything to do with CKEditor, and is badly formatted.